# Right-Align Tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, html, input, materialize

I am trying to have part of a label for a text input field be right aligned.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mL19ybnt/) is an example fiddle.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name">First Name <span class="right-align">Top Right</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the 'Top Right' text be on the top right of the input. I tried adding the `right-align` CSS helper but it did not do anything.

I tried adding `style="float: right;"` which [kind of works](https://jsfiddle.net/mL19ybnt/1/) but the text is not perfectly aligned to the right

[image: float: right not working]

Is there a way to get this perfectly aligned against the right edge of the input field?

Comment: You need to adjust the width of your `label` to match its parents padding of `.75em` on each side, e.g. `width: calc(100% - 1.5rem)`. With that change, a float right will work.

Comment: Here is a working sample of that: https://jsfiddle.net/mL19ybnt/23/ ... just make sure the specificity of the CSS rule match the built-in rule (or you need to add `!important`, which I btw don't recommend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not a fan of over-using `position: absolute` to solve problems. Using this can cause performance issues because the browser has to [create a new stack element and render inside out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).  Especially because it's already in an absolute, so now you'd have 3 stacking elements, when really to do this, *none are needed*.

Less Dirty (no position, worst option) Fix:

```
.abcd {
  float: right;
}
label {
  padding-right: 1.50rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f4036zmg/

Why it works:  The label is positioned absolute, so it does not take into consideration the padding of it's container element (`.75rem`).  To get the left side align aligned correctly, it has `left: .75rem` which means the right is now `1.5rem` to the right because it's `width: 100%`.  Simply padding the label will force the float to move within the labels padded area.

Let me know if you want the whole thing to work without positions, it's pretty easy.  (However it looks like materialize.min.css is doing the work for you, in a very ugly way).

---

Semi-Clean (no position, ok option) Fix:

```
.abcd {
  float: right;
}
input[type=text].validate+label {
  width: auto;
  right: .75rem;
}
```

Here we override materialize.min.css (maybe that's not a good option, I don't know).  We reset the `width: auto` so the `right` will work and as before we have to pad for that `.75rem`

https://jsfiddle.net/gL7fhx2q/

---

Clean fix:

Html Changes Required:

```
<label for="first_name">
  <span class="">First Name</span>
  <span class="tar">Top Right</span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.input-field.col label {
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 .75rem;
  display: flex;
}
.input-field.col label > span {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.tar {
  text-align: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7bw2zghr/

Overriding materialize.min.css again, however should not cause issues for other designs.  Reset the left back to the correct position `left:0` and add padding like the input `padding: 0 .75rem`.  Now the label correctly match it's siblings.  Change the display of the label to a be a [flex container](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and wrap both texts so they are flex items.  Set the items to grow proportionally, and then correctly set the text of the flex item to right.

Comment: Don't recommend doing `padding-right: 1.50rem;` as it push the label outside its parent and can might cause other rendering issues, your second option is much better. Feel free to use my suggestion I posted in my comments at the question.

Comment: @LGSon `calc` in my opinion is a last resort (like `!important`).  Because the label is absolutely positioned it cannot cause rendering issues with other elements (unless there are other elements inside the parent div that are position absolute the OP has not told us about).

Comment: Are you kidding? .. you seriously mean you equal _calc_ with _!important_

Comment: And yes, that is exactly why, when _"the OP didn't told us"_ ... and the absolute element, when overflowed its parent, can also affect e.g. a clickable area outside the parent

Comment: Furthermore, if to use Flexbox, all what's needed is making the `label` a flex container and a left auto margin on its `span`. And note, your Flexbox sample is invalid, a `label` can't have a `div` as a child.

Comment: @LGSon calc can be worse than !important because it has to be calculated everytime, and depending on what it's calculating against (especially EM) causes (minor) performance problems. So having 10s or 100s of these cause actually cause real world problems in Rendering and Painting... `!important` can't cause that.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/mL19ybnt/15/

```css
.right-align {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name">First Name <span class="right-align">Top Right</span></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-field col s3">
    <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name">First Name <span class="right-align">Top Right</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use `position: absolute;` and then add any margin to align it correctly
e.g.

```
.right-align {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have many different text inputs and some of them have longer label text so 25px may be fine for some but may be too much for others. I was looking for a solution that will always align it to the right

Comment: 25px from the right, so the width of the label doesn't matter/

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @SamBattat when i run your code snippet, it throws error. May be script and link tags are not needed. i am not sure though.

Comment: I also included a jsfiddle link

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the width of the label to 91% as you are using the absolute position (top, left) to adjust its location and add float right to the span

```
input[type=text].validate+label {
  width: 91%;
}

.right-align {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add position absolute to a class and assign that class to element you want to align to the right of the input. You don't need to adjust anything else.

`.right-align {
position: absolute;
}`

Answer (score -2):

There is a lot of crazy CSS going on when I inspect it with Chrome. Where did you get this CSS? For some reason your label is positioned 10.5 px to the right which is throwing it off. Try this CSS...

```
.right-align {
  float: right;
}
label {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
.input-field{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Edit: I now see you got it from Materialize. I'm not very familiar with it, but the label being positioned 10.5px to the right and the `.input-field`'s `padding-left` and `padding-right` are causing the span to look too far to the right compared to the input. You need to remove that padding and make sure the label is positioned with `left: 0`. It might be a better idea to create custom classes for your label and for the span in the label, but the concepts I have shown here will work.